# Go language Syntax Confusion

Tags: go, syntax

So I'm brand new to Go, I am moving over from python b/c of concurrecny. 
Anyways I was looking at the [net/http package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-overview) and stumbled upon this:

```
client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: redirectPolicyFunc
}
```

So I see we are creating a client variable by referencing the original Client structure (I think that is how you would word that) but I am totally lost at the

```
CheckRedirect: redirectPolicyFunc
```

What the heck does the ":" mean and what are we doing with it? Also what are the things before and after it? I read the struct documentation and did the introduction to go tutorial but I didn't see anything, I may not of been looking hard enough. No doubt its simple I just have no idea where to start looking for answers.

---

Thanks for the answers everyone! This makes much more sense now!

Comment: The spec for composite literals: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals

Comment: Take the Tour of Go at least once, doing all exercises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a [composite literal](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals).

You're just creating an instance of the `http.Client` type and setting the
`CheckRedirect` property, then taking a pointer of it.

Comment: TIL. Thanks for pointing me to that. Just want to make sure I understood the documentation right but basically this is just a way to simplify setting initial values for variables within the structure instance? You can create and return an instance _and_ set variables all at the same time?

Comment: @SilverEnsign99 Exactly

Comment: @SilverEnsign99, yes that's correct. (properties or members rather then variables, but yes)

Comment: A nitpick: I'd suggest to rephrase: "...then taking an address of it". A pointer is not taken by this operation but produced as its result ;-)

Comment: @kostix Please feel free to improve the phrasing, my English is terrible